# Explain why there does not exist a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to explain why there does not exist a linear transformation T from $ℝ^5$ to $ℝ^5$ with range(T)=kernel(T).

I know the answer has something to do with dimensions because dim(range(T))+dim(ker(T))=dim(v), but I'm not sure how to explain this.

Comment: I mean, you've got mostly everything here. If the range of $T$ is equal to the kernel of $T$, then certainly their dimensions are the same. What is $\dim(\mathbb{R}^{5})$? Is it divisible by $2$?

Comment: That's what I'm not quite sure about.  I do not know what $dim(ℝ^5)$ is

Comment: Can you name a basis for $\mathbb R^5$? How many elements does that basis have?

Comment: Oh, so I think the dimension of $ℝ^5$ is 5... which is not divisible by 2.

Comment: but what does not being divisible by 2 show?

Comment: never mind, I understand it now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: odd+odd=even and even+even=even. So such a T does't exist on any odd dimensional vector  space

Answer (score 0):

if you want $ker=range$ then, by theorem, dimension of V would be even